# Limiting ffmpeg output

Tags: video, ffmpeg, conversion

I just started compiling my own ffmpeg. I noticed with the precompiled builds, there is not a lot of output while ffmpeg is running, -nostats option. Is there either a way to compile those types of options into ffmpeg when compiling, or set those somewhere so they do not always need to be typed in?

Thanks, and great board. I just found this, tons of great information here.

Comment: I would like it to show the same info i get from the pre-compiled zeronoe builds, fps, frame, time, bitrate, instead of the scrolling showing me each step, etc.

Comment: Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
frame= 7810 fps=338 q=-1.0 size=   73880kB time=00:05:25.64 bitrate=1858.6kbits/s speed=14.1x                                                                                            This is what I want it to show me

Comment: this is what my compiled version of ffmpeg shows me                                        frame=  596 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 size=    5143kB time=00:00:24.98 bitrate=1686.0kbits/
frame= 1075 fps=1074 q=-1.0 size=   18623kB time=00:00:44.95 bitrate=3393.6kbits
frame= 1525 fps=1016 q=-1.0 size=   33863kB time=00:01:03.83 bitrate=4345.8kbits
frame= 1980 fps=989 q=-1.0 size=   48902kB time=00:01:22.81 bitrate=4837.6kbits/
frame= 2435 fps=973 q=-1.0 size=   64691kB time=00:01:41.97 bitrate=5196.6kbits/
frame= 2902 fps=967 q=-1.0 size=   78124kB time=00:02:01.30 bitrate=5275.8kbits/

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve here. Are you using your compiled build on Windows as well? How is the `-nostats` option involved here? That option disables encoding stats, but you want the stats?

Comment: I mostly use ffmpeg for container switching, for my plex server.  I do a lot fo copying the video and audio from mkv to mp4. When I use the pre-compiled builds from Zeronoe, a simple ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4 I will post pictures below.

Comment: What I don't want. See how this takes up the whole screen, and scrolls until its complete.  !http://i.imgur.com/rruPTcz.jpg

Comment: This is what the static builds look like, both of these were with the exact same command ffmpeg -i input.mkv -c:v copy -c:a copy output.mp4.  !http://i.imgur.com/8a1hbAs.jpg

Comment: on the second picture I drew a box around the only part that actually changes as the file is processed, it counts the time, bitrate, speed, ect, i just doesn't scroll down the screen the whole time .

Answer (score 0):

Increase the width of your window. The scrolling will stop and the last line will be continuously updated.

Comment: Thank you for that, but I was really asking what the command switch is to display the output i get when I use the static builds from zeronoe, and if I could compile my own to have that built in. HIs doesn't have the running update, and when outputting to a text file, with a bunch of conversions, it gets quite long.